# Is it possible to setup DNS server by using webservices as datasource on Linux?

Tags: linux, dns

If i want to setup a DNS server on Linux by using webservice(SOAP) as datasource to resolve the name. Is it possible?

By the way, I find some API to code it myself with Java but I will use it for the last choice.

Thanks in advance
Wittaya

Comment: Do you want to wrap a DNS server around an existing SOAP data source, or wrap a SOAP interface around regular DNS?

Comment: I want to wrap a DNS server around an existing SOAP datasource. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood the question, and you want to provision a dns server from a SOAP service. You can, for example by generating zone files. Or you could use something like PowerDNS's pipe backend to do it on the fly, but that would probably be slower and flakier than generating the configuration in one pass.

Comment: This solve my question. I do not have enough knowledge to explain this cleard. Thanks Tobu. [Here](http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/135/powerdns-custom-dns-backend/) is the same thing I want to. By the way,this may be prove for the performance.:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether or not it is possible to use Java to resolve names into IP addresses, the answer is yes. See [`InetAddress.getAllByName(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName%28java.lang.String%29) for more information. You could create a SOAP interface based around invoking that method on an input argument.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear. I try to set up the dns server and have to use SOAP webservice as the zone file or the datasource for the dns resolver. Is there anything serve on this?